# Can you create a Arduino button that lets you executing certain things in your python program?

Tags: python, button, input, arduino, pygame

Is there a way to create an Arduino button that lets you do certain things in your python program. For example, can you make it so that it works like `pygame.K_LEFT` does in pygame but instead of a button being pressed on the keyboard it's on the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the communications between the Arduino and the PC/RPi (I assume) executing the Python.

There needs to be some interface between the two systems.  An easy way to implement this would be using a serial connection, but you could also use a network connection.

So to keep the code simple, I'll present an example using Arduino serial.

Arduino C-ish code:

```
#define BUTTON1_PIN 5
#define BUTTON2_PIN 6

void setup() 
{
    pinMode( BUTTON1_PIN, INPUT ); 
    pinMode( BUTTON2_PIN, INPUT ); 

    Serial.begin( 115200 );  // fast
    Serial.write( "RS" );    // restart!
}

void loop() 
{
    // TODO: Handle de-douncing (or do it in hardware)

    if ( digitalRead( BUTTON1_PIN ) == HIGH )
    {
        Serial.write( "B1" );   // Send a button code out the serial
    }
    if ( digitalRead( BUTTON2_PIN ) == HIGH )
    {
        Serial.write( "B2" );  
    }

    // etc... for more buttons, whatever
}
```

On the PC/RPi side, listen on the serial port for instructions from the Arduino:

```
import serial

# Change for your com port, e.g.: "COM8:", "/dev/ttyUSB0", etc.
serial_port = serial.Serial( port='/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=115200 )  # defaults to N81

while ( True ):
    command = serial_port.read( 2 )  # read 2 bytes from the Arduino
    if ( len( command ) == 2 ):
        if ( command == b'RS' ):
            print( "Arduino was Reset" )
        elif ( command == b'B1' ):
            print( 'received button 01' )
        elif ( command == b'B2' ):
            print( 'received button 02' )
        elif ( command == b'qq' ):
            # Arduino says to quit
            print( 'received QUIT' )
            break

serial_port.close()
```

It's all fairly simple.  Whenever a button is pushed on the Arduino a code is written down the serial line.  The Python program listens on the serial line, reading the 2-letter (byte) codes.  When it receives a code it recognises, something is done, otherwise the code is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't go into a lot of detail here, but I'm assuming that you're talking about having your Python program run on a local computer, with the Arduino and its button(s) connected to the computer via USB. With many Arduino models (according to https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/ Leonardo, Esplora, Zero, Due and MKR Family), you can use the Arduino Keyboard library to send keystrokes to your computer via the USB port, but I also did this with an Arduino Uno for one installation some years ago by uploading different firmware to it -- if you have an Arduino Uno (or maybe one of the other models not mentioned above), you can see various pages about this by doing a search for Arduino Uno USB keyboard firmware.